Cannot get form response in onFormSubmit as it reads as undefined
When I try and get a form response from onFormSubmit(e), it returns {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"604XXXXX"}, which does not include the values property. It seems like I am missing a scope but I dont know which one.
My code is
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    Logger.log('Named Values: ' + JSON.stringify(e.namedValues));

    var URL = e.namedValues['URL'] ? e.namedValues['URL'][0] : null;
}

My current scopes are
    "oauthScopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
      ]

TL:DR
I expect a valid e.values response, but it does not contain the values property.

There are two onFormSubmit triggers and each generates different Event Objects.

script bound to the Form. This appears to be what you have done.
script bound to the linked Sheet. This is the trigger that generates Named Values, etc.

Solution:

delete the Form-based trigger.
create a Link Sheet (if you don't have one already)
copy the script to the Sheet Script Editor, and create an installed trigger.
submit a form and enjoy.

